# How to send array buffer data along with string/json to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraybuffer

I need to send image data (read as array buffer) from client page, along with additional string/json information generated by page, to NodeJS server in one request. I need both parts to be processed in one request as further image processing by server depends on that string/json sent along. What are ways to both send those by client and then parse them by server so it meets those criteria?

Comment: `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` should work on typed arrays just fine.

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is a multipart request using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

FormData can be used as the `body` in fetch and supports [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).
An example would be this:

```
var binary = new Uint8Array(2)
binary[0] = 65
binary[1] = 66

var fd = new FormData()
fd.append('json_data', JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}))
fd.append('binary_data', new Blob([binary.buffer]))

fetch('https://example.com/receive', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: fd
}).then(console.log)
```

**Note**: If you are using `express` on your server, please be warned that `bodyparser` does **not** handle multipart bodies!

Alternatives for bodyparser would be `multer`, `connect-busboy` or `multiparty`.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with express.js you can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

From their docs:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```