# Save pdf file loaded in iFrame to database after edit Oracle APEX

Tags: pdf, iframe, oracle-apex

I am trying to save a PDF file that is loaded in an iFrame after sign it, i am using the (*PSPDFKit* standalone) in *Oracle APEX* 190200 version.
I need save the is database instead of download file.

How I can get file and save file in database through AJAX callback?

Screenshot:
[image: page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`instance.exportPDF()`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/web/PSPDFKit.Instance.html#exportPDF) to get the PDF as an `ArrayBuffer`. Then you can convert the [ArrayBuffer to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291288/how-to-send-array-buffer-data-along-with-string-json-to-nodejs-server) and send it to the server. Hopefully, this should solve your issue.

I would suggest you to reach our support directly. We offer a blazing fast assistance and the questions are handled directly by the Web team: https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/.

Comment: thanks , i tried that using below code but this error appear " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exportPDF' of undefined"           
     
       const content = await PSPDFKIT.instance.exportPDF();
       console.log(content);

Comment: thanks, it's working fine ,i just did something by wrong way.